# How can I treat mouse input in Unity for an FPS as a Vector2 like Input.GetAxis or a virtual joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi StackOverflow community, I have one common issue and need your help.
I am a newbie in Unity but trying each day to improve my knowledge, sooo...
Recently, I completed one of the Udemy courses and now trying to add new features and run the game on a Mobile device. I added a Virtual joystick asset and already changed movement with that Joystick.
But for aim functionality, it is hard for me to change to Joystick.

What I changed already:

```
//moveInput.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); // PC
//moveInput.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); // PC

moveInput.x = movingJoystick.Horizontal; // Mobile
moveInput.y = movingJoystick.Vertical; // Mobile
```

But now I need to change `Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;` to something similar to `weapon.Joystic.Horizonral` as I did with movement.

Please, advise some good implementations.

Here is a part of the code that handles character's and weapon rotation:

```
if (canMove && !LevelManager.instance.isPaused)
        {
            //moveInput.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); // PC
            //moveInput.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); // PC

            moveInput.x = movingJoystick.Horizontal; // Mobile
            moveInput.y = movingJoystick.Vertical; // Mobile
            
            moveInput.Normalize();

            //transform.position += new Vector3(moveInput.x * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed, moveInput.y * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed, 0f);

            theRB.velocity = moveInput * activeMoveSpeed;

            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition; 

            Vector3 screenPoint = CameraController.instance.mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.localPosition);

            if (mousePos.x < screenPoint.x)
            {
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, 1f, 1f);
                gunArm.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, -1f, 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
                gunArm.localScale = Vector3.one;
            }

            //rotate gun arm
            Vector2 offset = new Vector2(mousePos.x - screenPoint.x, mousePos.y - screenPoint.y);
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            gunArm.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
        }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about FPS controls in Unity but a common approach is to first lock the cursor (so it doesn't go everywhere), set it to invisible, and treat it as another axis.

The first parts will involve the following [Cursor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.html) APIs. Also, make sure you disable and reenable these as the player enters and exists UI vs the FPS parts of your game!:

```
Cursor.lockState = CursosLockMode.Locked;
Cursos.visible = false;
```

The second part is simply another usage of [`Input.GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).  As the documentation for that API mentions, you can use `"Mouse X"` and `"Mouse Y"` as axis:

```
Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
```

That doc also mentions the following, in case those exact strings aren't working for you (but AFAIK, those two are the defaults when making a new unity project):

> To set up your input or view the options for axisName, go to Edit >
> Project Settings > Input Manager. This brings up the Input Manager.
> Expand Axis to see the list of your current inputs. You can use one of
> these as the axisName. To rename the input or change the positive
> button etc., expand one of the options, and change the name in the
> Name field or Positive Button field. Also, change the Type to Joystick
> Axis. To add a new input, add 1 to the number in the Size field.

Comment: Hi @Foggzie, thank you for your answer! I tried it, but with no success. I need not only to convert it as Vector2, but also to change the usage of mousePosition to another one. I tried that: `Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(weaponJoystick.Horizontal, weaponJoystick.Vertical, 0f);` but it does not work. =( I think I am going wrong way at all. Currently, rotation of character goes from mousePosition, but I trying to change it to virtual Joystick.